# Wordpress - Error when changing permalinks structure for a site installed at /blog subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

My site is www.topdoctors.co.uk and we have a Wordpress installation at www.topdoctors.co.uk/blog.

I'd like to change the permalinks structure of posts to something other than the default, ideally to the post name. So I try selecting "post name":
[Post name:       https://www.topdoctors.co.uk/blog/sample-post/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7PEo.png)

However, when I do this, I get a "too may redirects" error on the homepage. Presumably this is because all of the posts are located under a virtual directory, which is called "blog". But since my home page is located at www.topdoctors.co.uk/blog it's bouncing between this and the virtual directory. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably an issue with your .htaccess file. I'm guessing you have two, one in the main directory and one in the Wordpress install. When you save permalinks in Wordpress it creates a .htaccess file. If you have something in the main .htaccess file pertaining to the blog it will likely cause a conflict.